# Kubuntu 17.04 How to do fully automatic update with discover?

Tags: kubuntu, update-manager

i am using Kubuntu 17.04. and the `daily` update message is really annoying me. In discover settings i have adjusted `Check for updates` every 2 weeks and `install security updates without confirmation`. But every day i get the update message and i also need to confirm by password.

As i am the only user here at my computer, how can i do all updates fully automatic?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is few answers for that. On below link you have few.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates

I prefer aptitude&cron method. It was worked on my distribution 17.04 and on actual 17.10. If you will get a problem, please feel free.

Comment: Hi Axel, please do not add link only answers. Keep the link for reference and include the essential parts here.

Comment: As it is the only answer, and it is at least a little helpful, even in a slitghly different way, i acceptedt it

Comment: I don't see the point to copy something if it was writing very clearly ;)